# Maven OSXBundle Plugin Does Not Produce DMG and APP cannot open

Tags: java, macos, maven

I am working on creating a hello world app using [the Mac OSX Bundle Plugin for Maven.](http://mojo.codehaus.org/osxappbundle-maven-plugin/)  I followed the instructions for the XML plugin

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>osxappbundle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.osxbundle.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is supposed to create a DMG file.  However when I run

```
mvn clean package osxappbundle:bundle -DmainClass=com.example.osxbundle.Main
```

My target directory contains a `.app` that cannot be opened (see image) and no DMG.  What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

[image: APP cannot be opened and no DMG]

Also I tried upgrading to plugin version 1.0-alpha-2 and opening the app from the command line.  This is what I got:

```
sudo open ./target/osxbundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT/osxbundle.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file 
./target/osxbundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT/osxbundle.app.
```

Comment: That maven plugin page hasn't been updated since 9/9/2012, and searching around shows a bunch of people forking it on GitHub around a year ago and trying to fix various issues that it has.  Likely it's now defunct and out-of-date in regards to the various OS X and XCode releases since then...